# Request had insufficient authentication scopes youtube api

Tags: oauth, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I have enabled Youtube Api and added Scopes from oAuth Consent screen in Cloud Console it was working before can anyone solve this issue

```
  {
    I/flutter (21147):   "error": {
    I/flutter (21147):     "code": 403,
    I/flutter (21147):     "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    I/flutter (21147):     "errors": [
    I/flutter (21147):       {
    I/flutter (21147):         "message": "Insufficient Permission",
    I/flutter (21147):         "domain": "global",
    I/flutter (21147):         "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
    I/flutter (21147):       }
    I/flutter (21147):     ],
    I/flutter (21147):     "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    I/flutter (21147):   }
    I/flutter (21147): }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]; then do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic) and provide a [mre].

Comment: By the way, what's the point of having linked your post to the profile of Ibrahim Ulukaya?

Comment: @AdarshSingh please remember to only use English on Stack overflow.

Comment: @DaImTo I am Having difficulty in changing status of stream to testing and live because i don't have access token.It gets expired in 3600 seconds only do you know any way to keep that alive I can't use silent login or login

Comment: Access tokens expire after an hour you need to use a refresh token to request a new access token.

Comment: how to get refresh token in flutter i need to make a transition in youtube from a admin account which is not logged into normal user account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

Means that you have not authorized your application with the [scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#youtube) required.

When you authorize a user you tell the user what [scope](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#youtube) of authorization your application needs.

lets say you were trying to do a [video.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)

In order to call the [video.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) method you need to be authorized with one of the following scopes

[image]

If you authorized your user with say `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly` then you do not have the scope of authorization that you need in order to use that method.

The solution is to check the documentation to find out which scope of authorization the method you are calling requires.  Once you know that you can change the scope in your code and request authorization of the user again.

## it was working before

I doubt that greatly if it was working before then you have changed or removed the scopes from your code.  This is an all or nothing thing its not something that will randomly stop working.

Comment: In my case, it was working before -more than six months ago, when I last tried to connect to the API from my website-, and having literally done nothing to the code, now it doesn't work.

Comment: Check Scopes it will work